# Getting rid of an optional space in Python regex script

Tags: python, regex, expression

I'm having a bit of an issue with my regex script and hopefully somebody can help me out.

Basically, I have a regex script that I use re.findall() with in a python script. My goal is to search various strings of varying length for references to Bible verses (e.g. John 3:16, Romans 6, etc). My regex script *mostly* works, but it sometimes tacks on an extra whitespace before the Bible book name. Here's the script:

```
versesToFind = re.findall(r'\d?\s?\w+\s\d+:?\d*', str)
```

To hopefully explain this problem better, here's my results when running this script on this text string:

```
str = 'testing testing John 3:16 adsfbaf John 2 1 Kings 4 Romans 4'
```

Result (from www.pythonregex.com):

```
[u' John 3:16', u' John 2', u'1 Kings 4', u' Romans 4']
```

As you can see, John 2 and Romans 4 has an extra whitespace at the beginning that I want to get rid of. Hopefully my explanation makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the digit and space optional as a single unit by grouping with parens (`?:` just to specify it's non-capturing),

```
'(?:\d\s)?\w+\s\d+:?\d*'
 ^^^    ^
```

Which produces,

```
>>> s = 'testing testing John 3:16 adsfbaf John 2 1 Kings 4 Romans 4'
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\d\s)?\w+\s\d+:?\d*', s)
['John 3:16', 'John 2', '1 Kings 4', 'Romans 4']
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! I was trying to do exactly this but I didn't know the syntax for it.

Comment: @Matthieu Glad to help! Good to refer to http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewriting your regular expression, you can always just `strip()` the whitespace:

```
>>> L = [u' John 3:16', u' John 2', u'1 Kings 4', u' Romans 4']
>>> print map(unicode.strip, L)
[u'John 3:16', u'John 2', u'1 Kings 4', u'Romans 4']
```

[`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) here is just identical to:

```
>>> print [i.strip() for i in L]
[u'John 3:16', u'John 2', u'1 Kings 4', u'Romans 4']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension you can do it in a single line:

```
versesToFind = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'\d?\s?\w+\s\d+:?\d*', str)]
```